# How to destructure nested object with null value using default value

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

When trying to destructure a nested object which could be null, the default value is not being used.

I have accomplished this by destructuring in multiple stages, but would rather do it in a single stage if possible.

```
const obj = { a: null };
const { a: { b, c } = {} } = obj;
```

This results in error:
`Cannot destructure property 'b' of 'undefined' or 'null'`

I would expect b and c to be `undefined`

Comment: `the default value is not being used` what default values?

Comment: How can you destructure something that does not exist?
You would have to set the object to be intialized `const obj = { a: { b, c} }`

Comment: @AZ_ The default value is denoted by  `= {}` on the second line of code. So, if `a` is `undefined`, an empty object will be destructured instead.

Comment: @Michael That is the purpose of the `= {}`. So if `a` is `undefined`, an empty object will be used for the purpose of the destructuring.

Comment: Ok, `default` value only assigned if the `property` does not exist(`undefined`).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the [default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values) to be used, the value which you are destructuring must be `undefined`.

```js
const obj = { a: undefined };
const { a: { b, c } = {} } = obj;

console.log(b, c)
```

Comment: But if a is null instead of undefined, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `null` to empty object in a temporary object. Using `map()` on entries of object change `null` to empty object `{}` and then convert it to object using [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
const obj = { a: null };
const { a: { b, c } = {} } = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(x => x[1] === null ? {} : x));

console.log(b,c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like this after [transpiling](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvGBDAXDMArgDZEwC-A3AFCiSya4YzwA0Mw5qGZnaCiFIA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.4.4&externalPlugins=):

```
var obj = { a: null };
var _obj$a = obj.a;
_obj$a = _obj$a === void 0 ? {} : _obj$a;
var b = _obj$a.b,
    c = _obj$a.c;
```

Here `_obj$a` is the temporary variable referencing `obj.a`. If a default value is provided, it will only check this value against `void 0` (or `undefined`) and not against `null`

You *can* still do this using destructuring. But, a traditional `null` and `undefined` check is much easier to understand.

```
let obj = { a: null },
  a = obj.a,
  b, c;

if (typeof a !== "undefined" && a !== null) {
  b = obj.a.b;
  c = obj.a.b;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use destructuring twice and get the required output -

```
const { a = {} } = { a: null }
const { b = '', c = '' } = a || {}
```