# Error when destructuring a nested array from an object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I'm encountering an issue when trying to access nested data from an object that I'm receiving from an API using the useContext hook in a React application. The error message I'm getting is: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forecastday')". Strangely, when I tried to access the same data using vanilla JavaScript, it worked without errors.

I suspect there might be something wrong with my Context.jsx file, but I can't pinpoint the exact issue.

**OBJECT DATA**

```
weatherReport = {
      "location": {object Data},
      "current": {object Data},
      "forecast": {
        "forecastday": [
          {
            "date": "2023-03-07",
            "date_epoch": 1678147200,
            "day": {
              "maxtemp_c": 36.1,
              "maxtemp_f": 97.0,
              "mintemp_c": 17.4,
              "mintemp_f": 63.3,
              "avgtemp_c": 25.6,
              "avgtemp_f": 78.1,
              "maxwind_mph": 9.6,
              "maxwind_kph": 15.5,
              "totalprecip_mm": 0.0,
              "totalprecip_in": 0.0,
              "totalsnow_cm": 0.0,
              "avgvis_km": 10.0,
              "avgvis_miles": 6.0,
              "avghumidity": 22.0,
              "daily_will_it_rain": 0,
              "daily_chance_of_rain": 0,
              "daily_will_it_snow": 0,
              "daily_chance_of_snow": 0,
              "condition": {
                "text": "Sunny",
                "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/113.png",
                "code": 1000
              },
              "UV": 7.0
            },
        },
}
```

**React component code**

```
import { useGlobalContext } from "../context"

const ForecastReport = () => {
  const { forecast: { forecastday: [...forecastday] } } = useGlobalContext()

  console.log(forecastday)

  return <div className="forecast-box">
    Forecast Report
  </div>
}

export default ForecastReport
```

**error on console**

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forecastday')
```

**vanilla js**

```
const {forecast:{forecastday:[...forecastday]}} = weatherReport

    console.log(forecastday);
```

**console for vanilla js**

```
(7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

[https://replit.com/@djbravo12/WeatherApplicationOpenWeatherorg#src/context.jsx](my repl link)

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56108874/how-to-destructure-nested-object-with-null-value-using-default-value

Answer (score 0):

it's getting the error because when your page will refresh or render that time context data will be not set in the context state so. it's getting **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined"**

You need to write the condition when the context state value is stored then you will access it.

Answer (score 0):

`forecast` probably isn't available yet and so you're getting undefined issues.

Try updating in a useEffect hook after confirming that `forecast` is defined.

You could do something like:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useGlobalContext } from "../context";

const ForecastReport = () => {
  const { forecast } = useGlobalContext();
  const [forecastDay, setForecastDay] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (forecast) {
      setForecastDay(forecast.forecastday);
    }
  }, [forecast]);

  return (
    <div className="forecast-box">
      Forecast Report
    </div>
  );
};
```

You could then do whatever you like with `forecastDay` once it's value has changed from `null`.

Comment: thanks! but I've used condition in fetching Data function to get data 
`response.data ? setWeatherReport(response.data) :setWeatherReport([])`

Answer (score 0):

I am sure, this issue occurs because of your context.
So it will be much more clear when you share your context code.

By the way, I have tested this on my side. But works all fine.

Here is my code (App and Data Component).

```
// import context
import { DataContextProvider, useData } from "./contexts/DataContext";

const Data = () => {
  const {
    people: {
      users: [...usersInfo],
    },
  } = useData();
  console.log(usersInfo);
  return <div>hello Data</div>;
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DataContextProvider>
        <Data />
      </DataContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here is my Data Context code.

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";

const initialData = {
  type: "chat",
  people: {
    users: [
      {
        name: "Kevin",
      },
      {
        name: "Rebecca",
      },
      {
        name: "Pavlo",
      },
    ],
  },
};

const dataContext = createContext();

const useData = () => useContext(dataContext);

const DataContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <dataContext.Provider value={initialData}>{children}</dataContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { DataContextProvider, useData };
```

Hope this will help.