# Destructure nested object with possible null values

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I am receiving a nested object as a response from my API which looks like this:

```
 myObject = {
   name: 'client name',
   address: {
     building: 'building name',
     block: 'block name',
     street: 'street name'
   }
```

I am currently destructing it by

```
  const { name, address: {building, block, street}} = myObject;
```

The code above works fine when `myObject` has the `address` object, but it's possible to get a response with the `address` object as `null`. like:

```
  myObject = {
    name: 'client name',
    address: null,
  }
```

in that case, I get an error saying:  `Cannot read property 'building' of null`

I have tried destructing like below

```
const { name, address: {building, block, street} = {}} = myObject;
```

It only works if I get the `address` as `undefined`.

I have accomplished this by destructuring in multiple stages, but would rather do it in a single stage if possible.

Comment: Do you only have to handle `null` and `undefined`?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56108874/how-to-destructure-nested-object-with-null-value-using-default-value

Comment: @Unmitigated only `null`

Comment: @CodeThing the mentioned solution only works if I get `address` as `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a helper function to remove all null entries before destructuring to allow the default value to be used.

```js
const removeNulls = o => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).filter(([k, v]) => v !== null));
let myObject = {
  name: 'client name',
  address: null
};
const { name, address: {building, block, street} = {}} = removeNulls(myObject);
console.log(name, building, block, street);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in my case the address is not present at all.

Comment: @WahidullahShadab If it's not present at all, there should be no error. Your original code works fine for that case: https://jsfiddle.net/uw5hx1eL/